# Javascript - Get paste data before the paste event

Tags: javascript, paste

I'm making an app that will let users store their links, and in order to improve the user experience I was thinking of adding this functionality: When the user switches to the app it checks if the copied data is a link, and if it is then paste it to the input.

Is it possible to access the copied data before the `paste` event even happens? I'm totally okay with the user knowing that I'm trying to access their clipboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Support for accessing the system clipboard in JavaScript, even in modern browsers, is sketchy at best. A reliable cross-browser solution in JavaScript, in my experience, is likely impossible.

I believe older versions of Internet Explorer (*urrgggh*) exposed the system clipboard through:

```
window.clipboardData.getData('Text');
```

Note that in many modern production situations where the system clipboard is accessed, [the code snippets here for example](http://getbootstrap.com/components/), a small embedded Adobe Flash app (*urrrrgh*) is used and styled like a native button. I'm sure you've encountered a similar thing on your travels.

Though it seems to be the only well-adopted modern solution to this problem, I would not recommend using Adobe Flash. It's old technology.

Here is an [old link](http://www.jeffothy.com/weblog/clipboard-copy/) describing how you could potentially accomplish clipboard access with Adobe Flash (<del>un</del>fortunately I'm not a Flash expert so I cannot provide an example)